# programming add-ons, accessing backend of HRMS

Tags: c#, sql, mysql, vba

HR manager asked me to pick a good HRMS system for them to use

i have zero experience with HR systems.

one of the factors that i would look at is how "open" it is and whether i can connect to it and run select statements on it, and whether i can program add-ons.

can you recommend to me some HR systems that allow you to do these?

the organization needs software that will accomodate about 1000 employees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use [UltiPro](http://www.ultimatesoftware.com/) with about 3000 users.

There is nothing about it that cannot be extended and customized off the shelf. I have been amazed at the requests we have been able to fulfill in-house just by extending the existing instance.

Even better, none of this has interfered with any upgrades to the base.

FYI: I do not work for Ultimate Software.